# Why are the man pages for gvfs-commands not in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gvfs, manpage, info

[Here on unix.com](http://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?query=gvfs-info&apropos=0&section=1&os=opensolaris), there are man pages for

```
gvfs-cat            gvfs-less           gvfs-monitor-dir    gvfs-move           gvfs-rm             gvfs-trash          
gvfs-copy           gvfs-ls             gvfs-monitor-file   gvfs-open           gvfs-save           gvfs-tree           
gvfs-info           gvfs-mkdir          gvfs-mount          gvfs-rename         gvfs-set-attribute
```

But every year I see that there are more commands without `man` pages or `apropos` descriptions! Why is that? Where can I find documentation for all `gvfs` commands?

Comment: You should file a bug, I think the package is gvfs-bin: `ubuntu-bug gvfs-bin` -- Actually, here are the bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/gvfs/+bug/208596 and http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=520377

Comment: Package `gvfs-common` in ubuntu quantal (future release in October 2012) includes the manual pages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/gvfs-common/filelist

Comment: Do you think that helps? Is anybody reading that? The bug was reported in 2008

Comment: They just need to copy+paste the man pages from other linuxes

Comment: @PiliGarcia: Ubuntu could not "copy+paste" from other linuxes because **no linux had these pages**. Remember Solaris is not Linux. One cannot "copy+paste" from them, just like they cannot from your beloved MacOS, because they didn't *exist*. They had to be created first, *and they were*

Comment: Even if one could copy-paste, that would have to be discussed at Launchpad, not here.

Answer (score 7):

As you may have noticed, these [man pages](http://www.unix.com/apropos-man/opensolaris/0/gvfs/) were made by Sun for for Solaris, so Ubuntu cannot simply copy them due to copyright restrictions. The solution is for upstream (in this case, Gnome) to create the man pages themselves.

And, as already pointed out in the comments, this was requested via bug reports in both [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/208596) and [Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=520377) circa 2008. There were also [many bugs filed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance%20desc&bug_status=__closed__&product=gvfs&content=man%20pages) directly upstream about this issue.

[I personally filed a request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=657212) to Gnome in 2011, and attached the *.1.gz man pages files from Solaris as a suggestion. They were not directly used (for technical reasons), but a few months later they created and included the man pages for all gvfs commands.

The [upstream git commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/commit/?id=5e839711a36b4e145f3ba3033f2d0e3128df5f7a) including the man pages is quite recent, from June/2012 (and [a few more](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/commit/?id=e66a2c1006e0a4de88eb154223015c73cfa5947c) included and then [polished](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/commit/?id=02cf6dae51b1dc9218f4396ddd06f9a0127059f5) in August/2012), thus after Ubuntu 12.04 Precise was released.

Then, both Ubuntu and Debian must wait for a new upstream version to be released after. That only happened in [2012-07-16 in gvfs 1.13.3](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tag/?id=1.13.3) and [2012-08-12 in gvfs 1.13.5](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tag/?id=1.13.5).

But gvfs in Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal is currently at 1.13.7, so the man pages are [there](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/gvfs-common/filelist) in `gvfs-common` package

*See, the system works ;-)*